# How to make a copy when using rename() command?

Tags: php, rename, shortcut

Hello so I have this piece of code

```
$old_name = "C:\\inetpub\\users\\john\\cars.properties";
$new_name = "toys.properties";

rename($old_name, $new_name) ;
```

It changes the name of cars.properties to toys.properties but I dont really want to change the original cars.properties file, is it possible to the code itself can make a copy instead of me making a shortcut? If so I would really appreciate it!

Comment: [copy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)?

Comment: Umm, use [`copy()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@phpscrub simply by setting it this way:

```
$old_name = "C:\\inetpub\\users\\john\\cars.properties";
$new_name = "C:\\inetpub\\users\\john\\toys.properties";

// copy and rename at same time ;-)
copy($old_name, $new_name);
```

so the `cars.properties` file will be copied to the new file renamed `toys.properties`

Comment: I already found it by doing this; rename(copy($old_name, $new_name)) ;    thanks anyway :)

Comment: ok but just **copy($old_name,$ new_name)** it is enough because you assign it to $ new_name with a new name and already so you have the same file copied and renamed. ;-)